# Eliminating empty elements when marshalling with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

Using JAXB (2) is it possible to ensure that null values are not marshalled as () empty elements.  For instance

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    protected String name;
}
```

Currently if name is *null* then I am marshalling

```
<root>
  <name/>
</root>
```

I would like to produce

```
<root>
</root>
```

instead.

Comment: You must've done something wrong somewhere - when `name` is null, JAXB will not marshal the element at all. Your field has to contain an empty String, rather than a null.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that.  You were right and I had missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u have missed something.. as u marshal it ,the string u are passing must not be null as with string null is also an string.. so in my opinion u must pass empty string rather than null.